# Using a for loop to display an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am new to arrays, and I have been trouble with making a for loop work with an array. What do I need to do?

```
function start() {
    var arrPeople = ['Adele', 'Ted', 'Jo', 'Jim', 'Emma', 'Kate', 'Christopher'];
    var text = '';

    for (i = 0; 1 < arrPeople.length; i++) {
        text += (arrPeople[i] + '<br />');
    }
}
```

Comment: please give what exactly do you want?

Comment: try changing the 1 to i

Comment: if you want to avoid the for loop and only want to join the array element with `<br/>` tag you can also use this 
`text= arrPeople.toString().replace(new RegExp(',', 'g'), '<br/>')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a couple of minor errors in your function. The [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) statement is three parts: variable initialization, a condition that's checked after each loop, and an action that's performed after each loop. You had mistyped your condition as `1 < arrPeople.length` which would always be true. Also you weren't [returning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) a value from the function to be used by the calling code.

```
function start() {
    var arrPeople = ['Adele', 'Ted', 'Jo', 'Jim', 'Emma', 'Kate', 'Christopher'];
    var text = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < arrPeople.length; i++) {
        text += (arrPeople[i] + '<br />');
    }
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pick your poison ...

you can also use **array.foreach** ...

```
function start() {
    var arrPeople = ['Adele', 'Ted', 'Jo', 'Jim', 'Emma', 'Kate', 'Christopher'];
    var text = '';

    arrPeople.forEach(function(person) { 
        text += person + '<br />';
    });
}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

here's an possibly an even simpler solution using **array.join** ...

```
function start() {
    var arrPeople = ['Adele', 'Ted', 'Jo', 'Jim', 'Emma', 'Kate', 'Christopher'];
    var text = arrPeople.join("<br />");

    text += "<br />";
}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

or if you prefer, you can also use the functional style using **array.reduce** ...

```
function start() {
    var arrPeople = ['Adele', 'Ted', 'Jo', 'Jim', 'Emma', 'Kate', 'Christopher'];

    var text = arrPeople.reduce(function(txt, itm) { 
        return txt + '<br />' + itm;
    })

    text += "<br />";
}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: Some good options there, but you repeated the OP's mistake of not returning anything from your functions!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to display the list of names in the array vertically.  You can do it without `for-loop`.

```
function start() {
    var text = [ 'Adele', 'Ted', 'Jo', 'Jim', 'Emma', 'Kate', 'Christopher' ].join( '<br />' );
}
```

You can use `join` to concatenate each array item and you can specify a separator for each.  This way there is no extra `<br/>`.  see [array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Good thought, but you repeated the OP's mistake of not returning anything from the function.